# Should I run before or after the workout

Tags: running, training

I've been going to some different gyms in the past few years and at every new place I would ask for a new training plan. One radical difference I observed was that some suggested me to run on the treadmill before the workout, others after the workout, some also said it was better to run before AND after.

I'm really not getting it, what is the actual difference?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/395/cardio-before-or-after-exercise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cardio before or after exercise?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/395/cardio-before-or-after-exercise)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume your workout consist of weightlifting or other strength training. This mostly consist of short, high intensity exercises, which are likely mostly done anaerobic.

**Running before this workout**, means your body is warmed up, the activity of your cardiovascular and pulmonary systems are increased and your body has started to make sure you have enough energy to workout. So if you then start to workout, you'll basically have a flying start because you're body is well prepared.

Because the workout itself is mostly anaerobic, your body will slowly but surely create more lactic acid, because of all the glycogen that wasn't properly oxidated. **So if you run after your workout**, your body will take this lactic acid and start using it as a fuel and thus also get rid of it.

However, it is important that you run at moderate intensity, [because you need sufficient oxygen to oxidate the lactic acid](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/492/what-is-the-purpose-of-cooling-down/497#497) and don't want to be creating more! **So generally it won't really be running, but rather jogging**.

As Stefano comments: your (anaerobic) workout will deplete your glycogen storage. If you then start to **jog** afterwards, you'll body will have not much choice then to use fat as it's main source of energy. So jogging after your workout is a great way to burn fat, [but be sure to workout at the right intensity.](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/249/8)

[image]

<sub>Working out at a moderate intensity means you'll burn the most fat.</sub>

Comment: oh man, that's a great answer, very descriptive. Thanx a bunch!

Comment: Can you add any studies to substantiate your opinion?

Comment: @JoaquinG, the part about warming up is basic exercise physiology. As for the cooling down, [I can refer to my answer on the cooling down question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/492/what-is-the-purpose-of-cooling-down/497#497)

Comment: Does this depend on what you are trying to achieve, burn fat or build muscle?  I was told, if you want to burn fat you run after your work out because you've used up all other energy sources so when you run/sprint post weight lifting for 25-30 minutes will focusing mostly on fat.  This is just what I was told I would also like more clarification.

Comment: @Stefano, I updated my answer for you :-)

Comment: @Ivo: this is what I hate about fitness, all the different stories you hear :)
So my fitness instructor told me that working out on a moderate level to burn the most fat wasn't true anymore. I don't know what to believe anymore...

Comment: You can look at it pragmatically @priktop. Which of the two are you able to keep up longer: 60 or 80% of your VO2max? I bet 60%, so you're more likely to exercise longer, than at 80%. As for the burning fat at lower intensities, that's pure exercise physiology, so if that's wrong they can burn all the textbooks I had to read in grad school :-)

Comment: So you're saying that its best to properly warm up beforehand then do the main cardio after?

Comment: That would definitely help get your body ready for actually fat burning exercise @rmx. Worst case you just worked out 10 minutes longer!

Comment: Adding to what Stefano said: you wake up glycogen depleted before you eat in the morning.  So if you go jogging first thing, this is another good option for fat burning.